# Update minicart.phtml when I update my product quantity

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I have made a pair of modifications in `"/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/mohawk/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart"`, a pair of lines that calculates number of carries through the price (If price is 300€, it´s a carry).

Well, my problem is that I buy a product with price 8.20€ and my minicart shows this:

[image]

It´s correct, but if I modify the quantity, it doesn´t change until I refresh de page:

**WRONG:**

[image]

**CORRECT: (AFTER REFRESH THE PAGE)**

[image]

The web only update the price, but no my lines...

Any solution to this? It´s going me crazy.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to your specific theme that you've installed. However, I can tell you that I have modified the minicart many times. The data for the minicart is supplied from a specific data provider class `\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart`.

Natively, when Magento loads/reloads the minicart, the source data comes from that class. You mentioned that you put this logic into a phtml template. Generally, the minicart data is rendered through the use of an html template containing knockout js such as 
    `vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.html`

OR one of the files located inside this directory
    `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart`

Your best bet will be to create a plugin containing an `afterGetSectionData()` method and add your new data to the array in order to provide it to whatever template you are using. This SHOULD work but because it sounds like your theme is doing something a bit different from native Magento, it's difficult to guarantee.